# Why is global intall of Django from packages not working? (calling via python)

Tags: python, linux, django

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04#global-install-through-pip
i am using this website to install django
this test : django-admin --version  is successfull
but when I type this command : python manage.py migrate
or this : python -m django --version
the following error is seen: No module named 'django'
 Why is that so?
I used this tutorial  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1):

Your `django-admin` is pointing to some other Python executable.

If you type `which python` that is the Python you're currently using, and that Python does not see a django package.

I'd switch to using virtualenv's and then you know what you've pip installed and what you haven't.

Comment: when you say it is pointing to someother python.. what do you mean?
as in am i using python 3 while it is installed for python?

Comment: I tried the second method given in the tutorial too.. doesnt work :(
Ill try vitualenv, thanks!

Comment: could be. you might also have different versions of python2.7. can't know without more details

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3 you probably use `sudo pip3 install django` for intalling django. Now it is installed in python 3 not in python 2. If you run `python -m django --version` It directs to python2 not to python3. There is no Django installation in python2. You need to run python3 commands like `python3 -m django --version` and `python3 manage.py migrate`  It should work now.

Comment: Hey,
i tried that but did not work the error is---/home/khyati/anaconda3/bin/python3: No module named django
I had installed anaconda previously, my laptop had python already installed
Does it mean python could have been installed twice causing the error @lollercoaster is talking about

Comment: You can try uninstalling anaconda and reinstall python. 
I think its better if you can use a virtualenv.